# C#: Compare two list values having time in string format and extract only which is larger value

Tags: c#

I have two lists which has time in string format. I need to compare these two and extract the larger values in to another list.

```
List 1
"00:00"
"00:15"
"00:30"
"00:45"
....
"23:45"

List 2
"00:15"
"15:30"
"15:45"
```

now List 3 should contain all the values from list 1 which are larger than each value when compared to List 2.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: what do u mean by larger? list 1 and 2 size are the same?

Comment: no list 1 size is greater than list 2 size!

Comment: So how do we compare? Can't be based on indexes as lists aren't of same size

Comment: Isn't his just finding the highest value of list2, e.g. `var max = list2.Max();` and then filtering list1 and adding to list 3, e.g. `list3.AddRange(list1.Where(x => x > max));`?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and **explicit expected outputs** for those inputs.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm correct you want to compare each element witch are at the same position.

I whould go with:

```
        List<string> times1 = new List<string>(new string[] { "00:15", "01:01" });
        List<string> times2 = new List<string>(new string[] { "00:16", "01:00" });
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < times1.Count; i++)
            {
            if (int.Parse(times1[i].Substring(0, 2)) > int.Parse(times2[i].Substring(0, 2))) //check hours
                {
                result.Add(times1[i]);
                }
            else
                {
                if (int.Parse(times1[i].Substring(0, 2)) < int.Parse(times2[i].Substring(0, 2)))
                    {
                    result.Add(times2[i]);
                    }
                else  //check minuts
                    {
                    if (int.Parse(times1[i].Substring(3, 2)) > int.Parse(times2[i].Substring(3, 2)))
                        {
                        result.Add(times1[i]);
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        if (int.Parse(times1[i].Substring(3, 2)) <= int.Parse(times2[i].Substring(3, 2)))
                            {
                            result.Add(times2[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comparing hour first and minuts if necesary because it's only time.
If strings were date/time I whould DateTime vars to make conversion.

Comment: You don't really need to parse them if the format is always "hh:mm", because in this case the string comparison gives the same order as when you parse the hour and minute component and compare them individually.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but we can compare using `DateTime.Parse(List1[item1]) > DateTime.Parse(List2[item1])`. But my question was totally different. Still not able to get the answer :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
 var List3 = List1.Where(c => {Array.TrueForAll(List2.ToArray(), value => {
                                  c > value }}
                               );
```